# VB.Net access data table row by index and get field value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm wanting to get the values from specific columns in a data row by index, I'm having a problem accessing the value from the second row that is returned, below is what I'm trying to achieve

```
            Dim daSeries As New dsSVTableAdapters.clsCH
            Dim dtSeries As New dsSV.SeriesDataTable
            Dim drSeries As dsSV.SeriesRow

            dtSeries = daSeries.CSeries(1)
            drSeries = dtSeries.Rows(0)

            Dim RowCnt As Integer = dtSeries.Rows.Count 'Current RowCnt is 2 

                Select Case RowCnt

                    Case 1 'Only One row exists
                        hxValue1.Value = drSeries.YFieldName 'access 1st row YFieldName
                        hyValue.Value = drSeries.XFieldName  'access 1st row XFieldName
                    Case 2 'Two rows exists
                        For i As Integer = 0 To dtSeries.Rows.Count - 1
                            If i = 0 Then 'First Row index
                                hxValue1.Value = drSeries.YFieldName  'access 1st row YFieldName
                                hyValue.Value = drSeries.XFieldName   'access 1st row XFieldName
                            ElseIf i = 1 Then  '2nd Row index
                                hxValue2.Value = drSeries.YFieldName 'access 2nd row YFieldName
                            End If
                        Next

                End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drSeries variable points always at the first row. You should change to the second row inside the loop

```
Case 2 'Two rows exists
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtSeries.Rows.Count - 1
        ' Simply add this to your loop
        drSeries = dtSeries.Rows(i)

        If i = 0 Then 'First Row index
            hxValue1.Value = drSeries.YFieldName  'access 1st row YFieldName
            hyValue.Value = drSeries.XFieldName   'access 1st row XFieldName
        ElseIf i = 1 Then  '2nd Row index
            hxValue2.Value = drSeries.YFieldName 'access 2nd row YFieldName
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Ah the key ingredient, Thanks @Steve